# Matlab - linear regression - y-intercept by adding one column of ones

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I try to understand on the following link [linear regression](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html) the computing of coefficients beta0 and beta1 for the relation y = beta0 + beta1 x.

I understand the first computing of beta1 which is actually a simple least-squares regression, but with only one paramater to find (the slope coefficient) ?

In the example of "accidents", Why do they append a colum of ones to x array to compute the 2 coefficients :

```
X = [ones(length(x),1) x];
b = X\y
```

result :

```
b =

   1.0e+02 *

   1.427120171726537
   0.000001256394274
```

what is the underlying calculation with this column of ones ?

If anyone could explain to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like comment. But I am not allowed to do that, so writing as an answer.

They are adding column of ones to make it suitable for matrix multiplication. You have `y = beta0 + beta1*x`. In matrix multiplication form, it can be written as : `y = [1  x]* [beta0  beta1]'`. Please note transpose sign on beta matrix.

For reasons unkonwn to me, vectorization of variables is encouraged in Matlab and R. As per my knowledge, vectorization is expected to reduce resource consumption.

Comment: I would also add that if you calculate the slope separately from the bias (i.e. leave off the column of ones to find the slope), it could materially alter the value of the slope you find. This is why they do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Ones are often added to introduce "bias". In your case, try visualizing this equation:

```
y = w1 * x + c
```

The ones are added to represent another input, but which is always one.

```
y = w1 * x1 + c * x2(which is 1)
```

So, to model equations with constants(bias) in them, ones are added to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the equation y = beta0 + beta1 * x, beta0 is implicitly multiplied by 1. 
Put another way consider the *ith* (x,y) pair:

```
y[i] = beta0     + beta1 * x[i]
     = beta0 * 1 + beta1 * x[i]
```

That 1 that is multiplying beta0 for any *i* is where the ones vector is coming from.